# Can I only install the newest Android API to target lower API Version?

Tags: android, sdk, libgdx, version

Say I wanna make an app with :

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

My questions :

1. Do I need to install both "min SDK Version" as well as the target SDK version?
2. How if I only have SDK Version of 23 only? Can I make such setting? Or do I need to have both 22 as well as 8?
3. Can I debug such app with API / SDK Ver 21 phone?
4. Is it enough to only have the latest SDK version to develop any kind of app?

It is okay if there's any source (link) to comprehensive rule about such ruling, since I didn't found it even after extensive searching.

P.S. I don't know if this info is needed, but the app I wanna make is a libgdx game app.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. (the other answer is wrong)
2. You only need to have the version that you building with (`compileSdkVersion` in build.gradle). If you only have 23, then build with 23.

Usually, you should target the same version you build with. However, libgdx is not always fully tested with the latest Android. Check [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/versions.html) under **Android build version** to see what it has been tested for. This is the SDK level you should should target if you want to be sure not to have any problems. Right now, it is version 20 of Android.

I have been targeting Android 22 without issue (that I know of), though. I haven't yet released something higher than 20 yet so no guarantees that it's perfectly safe.

3. Yes.
4. Yes. Generally, the target SDK version and the build SDK version should match, but it works if you target a lower version than you're building with.

Targeting a later API basically changes some default behavior of apps. Theoretically, you should be testing on devices spanning the full range of API levels that you support, but in practice this is unnecessary for a libgdx game. But if you target a version that's too old, you might miss out on some newer features. For example, if you target <19, immersive mode (which is desirable for most games) cannot be supported.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have additional question btw, how to create libgdx project with lower api sdk? Since it doesn't seem have an option to choose one and automatically target the newest api sdk. Thanks.

Comment: You can change `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest. You can change `compileSdkVersion` in the build.gradle file inside the android directory of your project. But the way you worded the question makes it sound like you want to target a newer sdk than the one you are building with, which is impossible. `targetSdkVersion` should always be set to the same as or lower than `compileSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you need to install
2. If you have SDK Version of 23 only but you want to build it in version 22 then     also you need to install vesrsion 22 SDK.
3. Yes you can easily debug such app with API / SDK Ver 21 phone.
4. I think its enough.

Comment: hi. I wanna clarify something, at #1, you said that I need to install both, but in #4, you said that it's only the latest version needed. which one is correct?

Comment: hello.If you have latest sdk then set latest sdk version as target sdk version that's why i was telling yes its enough